# Reading JSON from file using GSON in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

I'm trying to read JSON from an internal storage file into a list of objects.

My code for reading the file and `GSON` is:

```
fis = openFileInput(filename);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

line = reader.readLine();

while (line != null)
{
     data.append(line).append("\n");
}

data.toString();

reader.close();
fis.close();

Type walletListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WalletClass>>(){}.getType();
walletList.add(new Gson().fromJson(data, walletListType));
```

However, I'm getting the error

> Cannot resolve method fromJson('java.lang.stringBuilder,
>   java.lang.reflect.Type')

The JSON I'm trying to load is (it's inside the square brackets because I've serialized it from a list of objects):

```
[
   {"balance":258,"walletName":"wallet 1"},
   {"balance":5222,"walletName":"wallet 2"},
   {"balance":1,"walletName":"wallet 3"}
]
```

I know a common fix for this is changing the import code from `org` to `com`, however I've already made sure it is `com`.

Comment: replace line = reader.readLine(); inside while loop

Comment: @Kirguduck That part works fine. But putting the reader inside the while loop doesn't change anything about the GSON error

Comment: if you use line = reader.readLine(); out of loop then you will read only first line of your json. add logs and check - what do you read. Now you read only part of json and as it appears this is cause of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Gson provide a lot of overloads for the `fromJson` method, here are their signatures:

[image: fromJson overloads]

But as you can see none of them takes the **StringBuilder** as first argument. That is what the compiler is complaining about. Instead you have constructors that take a String as first argument.

So replace this line:

```
walletList.add(new Gson().fromJson(data, walletListType));
```

with:

```
walletList.add(new Gson().fromJson(data.toString(), walletListType));
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it didn't work. I already have:
`data.toString();`

Comment: What error message do you get when you use ```data.toString()```? Obviously not the same, right?

Comment: My mistake, it did solve it. I assumed that having `data.toString()` outside of the `fromJson` method it would still work however it doesn't for some reason. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON's Type adapter to read and write files.
I have written this in kotlin, I hope it helps you.

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
      builder.registerTypeAdapter(YourData::class.java, MyTypeAdapter())
      return builder.create()
```

Sample Type Adapter

```
class MyTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<YourData>() {

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun read(reader: JsonReader): YourData {
    var element1
    var element2
    reader.beginObject()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      when (reader.nextName()) {
        "element1" -> latitude = reader.nextDouble()
        "element2" -> dropMessage = reader.nextString()
      }
    }
    reader.endObject()

    return YourData(element1, element2)
  }

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun write(out: JsonWriter, yourData: YourData) {
    out.beginObject()
    out.name("element1").value(yourData)
    out.name("element2").value(yourData)
    out.endObject()
  }
}
```

Usage (Read & Write)

```
fun saveData(yourData: YourData) {
    val string = gson.toJson(yourData)
    try {
      val dataStream = dataOutputStream(yourData)
      yourStream.write(string.toByteArray())
      yourStream.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
      Log.e("FileRepository", "Error")
    }
  }

fun getData(): List<YourData> {
    val data = mutableListOf<YourData>()

    try {
      val fileList = dataDirectory().list()

      fileList.map { convertStreamToString(YourDataInputStream(it)) }.mapTo(data) {
        gson.fromJson(it, YourData::class.java)
      }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
      Log.e("FileRepository", "Error")
    }

    return data
  }
```